# Grafana Open Source and SSO

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to configure SSO for grafana open source?
I'm using the open source solution, and I want to configure sso for my org.

Comment: Does [Setting SSO for Grafana](https://community.grafana.com/t/setting-sso-for-grafana/8511) or [Configure SAML authentication in Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/saml/) answer your question?